# How store the data of a column of a datagridview in an int array C#?

Tags: c#

I tried this:

```
int[] b = new int[10];

foreach (DataGridView Row row in datagridview1.Rows) 
{
    b[i]=
}
```

I need store the column into int array, the column contains only integers.

Comment: What did you try so far? What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: You completely changed the question. It's better to create a new question if you have a question that is different than the one you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want the values of the first column, which will have the index 0.

PS : It's better to do it with a for rather than a for each, since you want to add the values into an array, without an index (or an additional value) you'll have to write more code.

```
int[] b = new int[datagridview1.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    b[i] = datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    // the ?: is to check weither the value is null or not, then asign -1 if it's null
}
```

Comment: how to convert this code to display into richtextbox in c#

Comment: for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
{
printf("\nround %d",i);
for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
{
if(b[j]>0)
{
b[j]=b[j]-q;
if(b[j]<=0)
{
b[j]=0;
printf("\nprocess %d is completed",j);
}
else
printf("\nprocess %d remaining time is %d",j,b[j]);
}
}
}